# Python - How to connect to TOR proxy

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, tor

I've been trying to find out how I would connect to a TOR proxy or connect to the TOR network.
With the Socksipy module, I see that people (other stack overflow TOR python questions) can connect to a proxy, but I do not understand a concept.

```
import socks, socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050) #localhost??
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

I do get how you can connect to a TOR proxy, but the proxy is your local host just through port 9050?
Is this because everyone does not want to show real TOR proxy? 
How do I connect to a TOR proxy, and if this is the case, why?

Comment: you may try to cat the `torsocks.conf` to read more info about why `127.0.0.1` was set default.
or take a look at [this](http://linux.die.net/man/5/torsocks.conf)

Answer (score 2):

try this, before request

`

```
import socks
import socket
SOCKS_PORT = 9050  # TOR proxy port that is default from torrc, change to whatever torrc is configured to

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1",SOCKS_PORT)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

# Perform DNS resolution through the socket
def getaddrinfo(*args):
  return [(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 6, '', (args[0], args[1]))]
socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo
```

`